# Can RxJava be used to send messages only to the most recent subscriber?

Tags: android, rx-java

I've been given a requirement that when there are multiple observers, only the most recent subscription should receive messages.  I'll illustrate with sloppy code examples.

`val fooDisposable = mostRecentSubscriberObservable.subscribe(this::foo)`

Any time `mostRecentSubscriberObservable` emits an item, `foo()` is called.

Now this runs:

`val barDisposable = mostRecentSubscriberObservable.subscribe(this::bar)`

Now whenever an item is emitted, `bar()` is called, because `barDisposable` is the most recent subscriber. `foo()` is NOT called.

Now this runs:

`barDisposable.dispose()`

Now whenever an item is emitted, `foo()` is called. Now that `barDisposable` is gone, `fooDisposable` is the most recent subscriber, and receives the item.

Short of creating a custom `Subject` class (which seems rather complex), is there a way to do this - any existing `Subject` or combination of operators which would accomplish it? I can't seem to find anything like that.

Comment: This doesn't feel like the responsibility of `mostRecentSubscriberObservable`. IMHO, an `Observable` should neither know nor care about its observers. I'd look into creating a LIFO implementation of `Observer`, one that forwards the `on...()` calls to the most recent entry on a stack of wrapped `Observers`. In your case, you would call `mostRecentSubscriberObservable.subscribe(this::observerStack)`, where `observerStack` is the LIFO `Observer`. You would push `foo`, then `bar` onto that stack, eventually popping `bar` off.